# How to insert an object into an array which is inside an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, object

Suppose if we are having data like this, how can we use dot notations or anything to update the array(data2) inside the object data1 which is inside the array(data).

```
data = [
data1:
    {
        a:"1",
        b:"2"
    }
]

    // another array(data2 - below) I am having I have to push that array inside 
    data1 as an object
data2 = [
    {
        c:"3"
    },
    {
        d:"4"
    }
    ]
```

The response I want as below:

```
    data = [
data1:
    {
        a:"1",
        b:"2"
    },
data2 = [
    {
        c:"3"
    },
    {
        d:"4"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: data.push(data2) from what I read

Comment: `I have to push that array inside` pushing it is the answer.. what have you tried, does it work? if not what goes wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I didnt really understand your question but i think this is what you want?!

```
data = {
    data1:
    {
        a: "1",
        b: "2"
    }
}
data2 = [
    {
        c: "3"
    },
    {
        a: "3"
    },
    {
        d: "4"
    }
]

for (var key in data2) {
    for (var key2 in data2[key]) {
        if(data.data1[key2] != null){
            console.log("data.data1 with they key" + key2 + " could have been replaced/updated with " + data2[key][key2]);
        }
        console.log("key " + key2 + " has value " + data2[key][key2]);
    }
}
```

Result:

key c has value 3
data.data1 with they keya could have been replaced/updated with 3
key a has value 3
key d has value 4

Edit:

Why dont you just do

```
data["data2"] = data2?
```

Comment: I edited the question this would help to understand better

Comment: `data` is an array, not an object in the original post.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros yes thanks and I got this when I hit and tried everything

Answer (score 3):

---

```
var array = [];

array['data1'] = { 'name': 'a' }

var array2 = [{ c: 3 }, { d: 4 }];

array['data2'] = array2;

console.log(array)
```

OutPut:

[ data1: { name: 'a' }, data2: [ { c: 3 }, { d: 4 } ] ]

Comment: Please Try this

Answer (score 0):

I tried on myself and I got the solution. If we have to make another field in an object you just give a name like this

```
data.dataTwo
```

this will create another field with new name and now if we want to transfer or store an array in this we can simply do this

```
data.dataTwo = data2
```

This will assign that data2 named array in a new field what is given as dataTwo